# Python Queue.Queue wont work in threaded TCP Stream Handler

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, queue

i'm trying to make a threaded tcp stream handler class thread and the main thread talk, however Queue.Queue is not doing what i need it too, the server receives data from another program, and i just want to pass it into the main thread for processing here is the code i have so far:

EDIT: Updated using proposed answer, queue still does nothing i cant even get any print commands to work after i does the self.queue.put(info) its like the whole thing dies. However it doesn't give me any errors, but the stream handler/thread the data comes in on dies after i put the info into the queue.

```
class ThreadedTCPStreamHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
         SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)
         self.queue = self.server.queue

    def handle(self):
                while True:
                    try:
                        self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
                        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
                        command = self.data[0:2]
                        if command == "nr":
                            info = self.data[2:]
                            t1 = info.split("|")
                            title = t1[0]
                            self.queue.put(info)

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):

        def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True, queue=None):
            self.queue = queue
            SocketServer.TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=bind_and_activate)
```

And in a main thread class i have:

```
q = Queue.Queue()
server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPStreamHandler, queue=q)
ip, port = server.server_address

server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
server_thread.daemon = True
server_thread.start()
while True:
        try:
            item = q.get()
            print item
            q.task_done()
            q.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            server.shutdown()
            sys.exit(0)
```

However nothing is printing out and it wont pass the data, i know i'm doing something wrong, i just dont know what it is. If anyone has any insight that could help i would greatly appreciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the stream handler and the main thread need to be using the *same* `Queue` object for this to work. You're creating separate queue objects in each place. Either use `queue` as a global variable, if both the client and server code are in the same file, or do this:

```
class ThreadedTCPStreamServer(ThreadingMixin, TCPServer):
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True,
                 queue=None):
        self.queue = queue
        TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass,
                           bind_and_activate=bind_and_activate)

class ThreadedTCPStreamHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        self.queue = server.queue
        StreamRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            if not self.data:
                break
            cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
            command = self.data[0:2]
            if command == "nr":
                info = self.data[2:]
                t1 = info.split("|")
                title = t1[0]
                self.queue.put(info)
                self.finish()


q = Queue.Queue()
server = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPStreamHandler, queue=q)
ip, port = server.server_address

server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
server_thread.daemon = True
server_thread.start()
while True:
        try:
            item = q.get()
            print item
            q.task_done()
            q.join()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            server.shutdown()
            sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Updated original question with your answer, still having problems, see above.

Comment: @BrianSykes I've updated my answer. Looks like `self.queue` needs to be defined before calling `StreamRequestHandler.__init__`. Also, it looks like the `handle` method you provided is incomplete - there's a `try` with no `except`. It also look like it will cause an infinite loop, since you have a `while True:` with no way to break from it. My version above will break when you get empty data back from the `self.rfile.readline()` call.

Comment: Got it working now, thanks for the help chief, i figured out i had to define it before and then went back to look at this and saw the fix you proposed, so glad i was right, have a good one.

Comment: Is the first class supposed to be named like that?

Comment: @LetsPlayYahtzee Nope, that was a typo. Good catch!

Comment: @dano, Nice example, thanks. Another note, I think line `self.queue = self.server.queue` should be `self.queue = server.queue`

Comment: Can `StreamRequestHandler` be replaced with `BaseRequestHandler` since my TCP handler is inheriting from that?

Comment: Also can use `super` instead? Especially in the case `ThreadedTCPStreamServer` where there's multiple inheritance being used?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You can't use `super` (assuming you're using Python 2.x), because all the classes in the `SockerServer` module are old-style classes. If using Python 3.x it should work. The same principles in my answer can be used for `BaseRequestHandler` as well as `StreamRequestHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

Found I had to adapt a couple of things from the accepted answer.
This example works (at least in python2.7).

After starting the server you can test by repeatedly sending with netcat or similar:

```
echo "nrtest" | nc -4 127.0.0.1 50514
```

One can also send with the `logger` command on linux, but then the handler must look for other strings (this example checks that line starts with "nr", as pr OPs request).

```
logger -T -n 127.0.0.1 -P 50514 "Test message"
```

The result is as follows - broken into sections for readability.

Imports:

```
"""
Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/25246157/2045924
"""
import threading
import Queue
import sys
import SocketServer
from SocketServer import StreamRequestHandler
from SocketServer import TCPServer
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
```

Adding queue to TCPServer:

```
class ThreadedTCPStreamServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
    """ThreadedTCPStreamServer."""
    def __init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, bind_and_activate=True,
                 queue=None):
        self.queue = queue
        TCPServer.__init__(self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass,
                           bind_and_activate=bind_and_activate)
```

Add queue to StreamRequestHandler, tell "handle" what to do, and let "finish" just pass.

```
class ThreadedTCPStreamHandler(SocketServer.StreamRequestHandler):
    """ThreadedTCPStreamHandler."""
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        self.queue = server.queue
        StreamRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, client_address, server)

    def handle(self):
        while True:
            self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()
            if not self.data:
                break
            __cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
            self.finish()
            command = self.data[0:2]
            if command == "nr":
                info = self.data[2:]
                __t1 = info.split("|")
                __title = __t1[0]
                self.queue.put(info)
                self.finish()
    def finish(self):
        pass
```

Define globals and start.

```
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 50514

# QUEUE must be defined _outside_.
QUEUE = Queue.Queue()
QTIMEOUT = 1

# Setup instance of my own ThreadedTCPStreamServer with my own ThreadedTCPStreamHandler.
SERVER = ThreadedTCPStreamServer((HOST, PORT), ThreadedTCPStreamHandler, queue=QUEUE)
__IP, __PORT = SERVER.server_address

# Start the server
SERVER_THREAD = threading.Thread(target=SERVER.serve_forever)
SERVER_THREAD.daemon = True
SERVER_THREAD.start()

while True:
    try:
        #ITEM = QUEUE.get(block=True, timeout=QTIMEOUT)
        ITEM = QUEUE.get()
        print 'qsize({s}): {i}'.format(s=QUEUE.qsize(), i=ITEM)
        QUEUE.task_done()
        QUEUE.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        SERVER.shutdown()
        sys.exit(0)
    #except Queue.Empty:
    #    print 'Got Queue.Empty after waiting for {t}. Continuing...'.format(t=QTIMEOUT)
    #    continue
```

Now start sending something with `nc` or a similar tool.

To end the program, press `<ctrl>+C`.

`KeyboardInterrupt` will "work" if you send a packet.

1. Press +C
2. Send an extra packet
3. Voila, program finishes